# How to downgrade Sony Xperia Z1s C6916?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sony-xperia, downgrade

Edit: I got flashtool to work on pc. It seems the device and everything, but the program does not see downloaded firmwares, even if they were downloaded from the software itself.

What I'm trying to do is Downgrade my Xperia from Lollipop to Kitkat. I have looked this up, and this  requires me to use a tool called Flashtool and I don't know how to install the drivers for it, and I don't trust it because I think installing the drivers for my pc and I don't know how to install it in linux.

Because I basically can't install the drivers (im pretty sure I can't turn off driver authentication on my pc) and can't figure out how to install it on linux, I'm at a loss. I'm trying to use a .ftf file.

Does anyone have any pointers? Does this even have to be done with FlashTool? Could I use ADB? I would prefer installing Flashtool with Linux, if I have to use flashTool.

Comment: I don't know if there is a linux version for Flashtool. You'll need a Windows computer and it should be easy to flash then.

Comment: I edited the post. Basically, I got it to work on pc, but it won't see firmwares.

Comment: Can you explain how you did? There is a process you should follow to make things work.

Comment: I installed flashtool and the drivers normally. I then located a FTF file I had to the default location, then hit flash, flashmode. It comes up with the dialogue to select firmware, but absolutely nothing is listed. I then launched XperiFirm and downloaded a firmware through there and it still doesn't show up under flashmode.

Comment: Did you click on the 3-dots to select the firmware manually? Some files don't show on newer Flashtool versions.

Comment: Do you mean the source folder button? I can't seem to select a specific patch, the firmware selector only has the 3 dots with folder selection. If you meant that, it doesn't help.

Comment: Exactly, the source folder. Hummm, weird. What version did you install? Can be found in Help > About. Besides, does the file ends with .ftf? You probably downloaded in rar or zip fomat.

Comment: I am running version 0.9.23.1, I think it's the latest version. And I did verify they are FTF files. Remember, one of them I did download through the XperiFirm portion of the software.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67850/discussion-between-esqmo-and-ubersteak).